# User input money value in grails

Tags: grails, double, currency

I need to get a money value from the user, but the user can type the number in different formats:

```
1.234.234,78
1234566,26 
123,123,132.12
```

I don't know how to treat the variable.

I have to transform that value in Double type but if the user give me a value with `","` the program generate an exception, how can I handle this?

Comment: which format is 1.234.234??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle money then I recommend you a great grails plugin with many feature for currencies handling and conversions etc.

Have a look at [Currency](http://grails.org/plugin/currencies) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your domain `static constraints` use `matches` with the regular expression that handles currency format.

Then using `java.text.NumberFormat` allows you to  format double regardless of having comma in the input.